# Pushing community digest "unsubscribe from all" button doesn't update page

Tags: bug, community-digests

Pushing [community digest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/digests/current) "unsubscribe from all" button doesn't update the page or even closes the popup window. I need to refresh it manually.

See GIF below for details:

> [image: Unsubscribe from all]

It turns out that some update is done though, i.e. "Weekly" changed to "Off". I didn't notice that since it's covered by the popup. All subscriptions that are set to Off will be removed from the list after the page refresh (unexpected behavior for me).